# Operations On Functions

Tags: calculus

If we are given a function, let say $f(x)=4x^2+4$ and we divide the function to get $g(x)=x^2+1$ can we know in general which properties of the function will be affected? for example the roots, min/max points, etc.

Comment: They remain the same. You might want to be less specific ...

Comment: Are we dividing by a constant, another function, etc.?

Comment: I think you're looking for the word factor and not divide.

Comment: It was just an example, is I mean factor, or any other operations that can be done on a function

Comment: If you multiply for a negative constant max and min swap. You can also add constants, but roots change. You can change x into -x, this is just a symmetry along the y axis
Forget about adding, multiplying etc for something containing the variable x

Answer (score 1):

By applying composition of a linear operator $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ over another operator $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ not necessarily linear, most of the linear operator properties are preserved, treating the operator over an element $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.

For example:

- $\text{roots}\{g(f)\} = \{x,g(f(x))=0\}=\{x,f(x)=0\}=\text{roots}\{f\}$
- $\min \{g(f)\} = \{x_{min},\forall x, g(f(x_{min})) \le g(f(x))\}= $ $\{x_{min},\forall x, f(x_{min}) \le f(x)\}=\min\{f\}$, with $g \ne 0$, strictly increasing. The same applies for the $\max$ operator
- In general, for any linear operator $h$, such an integral, derivative, average, etc., both $g$ and $h$ commute, hence: $h(g(f))=g(h(f))$. For example: $\frac{d}{dx}\{g(f)\}=g\frac{d}{dx}f$

Which other properties?, which other operators?. I think the question is still too broad to answer that...

Comment: You might have forgotten  excluding $g=0$.